# How do I find the biggest odd divisor for an even number?

Tags: c++

How do I find the biggest odd divisor for an even number?

For example, 18 is the  number
The divisors are: 1 2 3 6 9 18

Biggest odd divisor: 9

Here is the code I have so far. It prints all of the divisors:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h> 

main() { 
    int i, n; 

    printf("Enter the number : "); 
    scanf("%d", &n); 

    printf("\nThe divisors are :\n\n");     
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
        if(n % i == 0) 
            printf("%d\t", i); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This isn't a proper question, just a request to solve the problem for you.

Comment: Divide the number by 2, until you reach an odd number.

Comment: Chris, i am try to write a C++ program to see  what is the biggest odd number that can be the divisor for even number. let me know if i am not clear

Comment: @user3865742 Show the code you actually have, and clearly explain where you're stuck [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28374072/edit) please!

Comment: #include <iostream>
# include <stdio.h>   

main()   
{   
 int i, n ;   
 printf("Enter the number : ") ;   
 scanf("%d", &n) ;   
 printf("\nThe divisors are :\n\n") ;   
 for(i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)   
  if(n % i == 0)   
   printf("%d\t", i) ;   
return 0;  
}

Comment: You are going at it bass-ackwards. Try to reason it out a bit before coding.

Answer (score 1):

Keep dividing by 2 until the result is odd.